# What is the best VNC tool to connect Ubuntu and MacOSX?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, osx-leopard

I need to help someone with installing some development packages and everything. I am running Ubuntu and the person I want to help is running MacOSX 10.5. What is the most easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) or [FreeNX](http://www.nomachine.com/download-preview.php)? We just tested the TeamViewer between Linux and Windows and it worked very good.

Answer (score 2):

A solution which works with built-in software of that two systems:

**On the Mac**: System preferences > Sharing > Screen Sharing

- Enable it, and in the further options ensure that "VNC users are
  allowed to join with password: XYZ" and which users/groups are
  allowed.
- *If you should need further info*: [Apple documentation on Screen Sharing](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/14065.html)

**On the Ubuntu computer**: Applications > Internet > Remote Desktop Viewer

- This starts the Vinagre VNC client.
- *If you should need further info*: [Ubuntu community documentation on VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC)

**Of course, with this solution** you have to go through the hassle of determining IP , firewall settings, etc, compared to rather easy tools like [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/), but you have the advantage of having no need for 3rd party software, and the related issues of trust.